# SharePoint Powershell creating a dynamic view with [Me] filter

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I am trying to create a list view DYNAMICALLY using PowerShell.
CAML query is

$viewQuery = `"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='PPL' /><value Type='User'>[Me]</value></Eq></Where>"`

This updates the view with PPL and value as "[Me]". but the list is not showing any data. But when I open the updated view and just save it, the list is showing current user data.

Why powershell caml query is not take [Me] as the value?

Any Ideas?

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please run the below PowerShell script as an admin on SharePoint Online Management Shell:**

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://{domain}.sharepoint.com/sites/{sitename}"
$ListName= "{listname}"
$ViewName= "{Test View}"
$ViewFields = @("Title","Dimension","Format","PPL","ProceedDate")

$Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='PPL'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value></Eq></Where>"
 
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
 
Try {
    #Connect to PnP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred
 
    #sharepoint online pnp powershell create view
    Add-PnPView -List $ListName -Title $ViewName -ViewType Html -Fields $ViewFields -Query $Query -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-host "View '$ViewName' Created Successfully!" -f Green
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

**Here is my test:**

This is my list:

[image]

Run the PowerShell script:

[image]

Create new view:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Elaborate answer. This worked. Thank you.